# Can't call odoo from iframe

Tags: iframe, odoo, odoo-15

I can't call odoo from iframe . Both odoo and iframe are in same Nginx server .I added
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
in Nginx configuration file .

[image: X-frame option deny here]

When i click open site in new window it opens  but the X-Frame option is  Deny here .
Is anything added in odoo to allow this  ?

Comment: Why do you still use IFRAME and Insecure HTTP in 2022?

Comment: actually this HTTP for testing purpose .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Home(Home):
    @http.route('/web/login', type='http', auth="none")
    def web_login(self, redirect=None, **kw):
        res = super(Home,self).web_login(**kw)
        res.headers.remove('X-Frame-Options')
        return res
```

Odoo denies x-frame-option in web_login . Just override the method and remove the option will work fine . And additionally needed to remove add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always; in Nginx configuration file